# Unity3d game occupies huge space in a ios device

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

The whole image resources of my game is less than 50MB. But the installation size in iphone is 292MB(it takes up only 90MB in android). I assume there should be something wrong about textures. So I duplicate an image folder(15MB) within the Resources directory. And the new installation file size expands to 400mb. How could an increase of 15MB pictures lead to a 108MB increase in ios installation size. I have been bothered by this issue for 2 weeks. Can anyone give me any hint?

Comment: What is the [Texture Format](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterOverride.html)?

Comment: @AliKanat It's automatic. I saw someone suggesting pvrtc as the format. But  there is no such option in the mac version unity3d.

Comment: You should run through [Unity's Build Size Reduction Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html).  The first step (digging through the editor logs) will at least tell you exactly where that memory footprint is coming from.